# How to prevent a developer from using a specific hook in a React project using ESLint?

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I have a React project and I have created a custom hook using the hook `useNavigate` that comes with the React router v6. The custom hook is working very well and now I need to prevent developers in this project from using the native `useNavigate` hook. I configured my ESLint script as follows. And I have installed the dependency "eslint-plugin-react-hooks" **The problem is, I'm getting the error "[eslint] Failed to load plugin 'no-react-hooks' declared in '.eslintrc.json': Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-no-react-hooks'"**

.eslintrc.json

```
{
  "extends": [
    "react-app",
    "plugin:no-react-hooks/recommended"
  ],
  "plugins": ["react", "no-react-hooks"],
  "rules": {
    "no-react-hook/use-navigate": "error"
  }
}
```

eslint-plugin-no-react-hooks.js

```
module.exports = {
  rules: {
    'use-navigate': {
      meta: {
        type: 'problem',
        docs: {
          description: 'Prevent usage of the useNavigate hook',
          category: 'Best Practices',
          recommended: true,
        },
      },
      create(context) {
        return {
          ImportDeclaration(node) {
            if (
              node.source.value === 'react-router-dom' &&
              node.specifiers.some(
                (specifier) => specifier.imported.name === 'useNavigate',
              )
            ) {
              context.report({
                node: node,
                message:
                  'Do not use the useNavigate hook. Instead, use "useCustomNavigate"',
              });
            }
          },
        };
      },
    },
  },
};
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a different approach and fixed the problem. Instead of preventing a developer from using the `useNavigate` hook, I set a rule to **prevent a developer from importing that method** through the `react-router-dom` module anywhere in the project as follows. (Also I added an exception using the `overrides` property to explicit a file to use the `useNavigate` hook)

eslintrc.json

```
{
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["src/helper.tsx"],
      "rules": {
        "no-restricted-imports": [
          "error",
          {
            "paths": [
              {
                "name": "react-router-dom",
                "importNames": [],
                "message": "Importing useNavigate from react-router-dom is only allowed in this file."
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "rules": {
    "no-restricted-imports": [
      "error",
      {
        "paths": [
          {
            "name": "react-router-dom",
            "importNames": ["useNavigate"],
            "message": "Importing useNavigate from react-router-dom is not allowed. Instead, Import useCustomNavigate from helper.tsx"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```